# Check if mentioned profile is a bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm making a Discord bot and I've been stuck on this problem for quite a long time. I'm trying to check if a mentioned user is a bot. I've used

```
message.mentions.members.first();
```

to check the mentions which are stored in the variable `profileMentionned`

```
let profileMentionned = message.mentions.members.first();
```

as the mentioned profile argument. But when I tried to put

```
profileMentionned.bot
```

in an if statement, it would never output a `boolean` value, it won't test if the user was a bot and would just come out as the default value I set my `var` which was `"undefined"`.

Here's my source:

```
case "profile":
    var isAdmin = "undefined";
    let profileMentionned = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!profileMentionned) return message.channel.send("Error message about mentionning a user")
    if (profileMentionned.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
    {
        isAdmin = "Admin boi";
    } else {
        isAdmin = "Member pleb";
    //Now here's the problem part
    if (profileMentionned.bot) isAdmin = "Bot";
    //I also tried with "if (profileMentionned === true) isAdmin = "Bot";"
break;
```

Thank you for answering! <3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users have a flag for bots, Members don't.
You need to do `profileMentionned.user.bot`.
Check the documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot).